# error when plotting map of joined sf geometries in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have been using a shapefile of a set of grid cells to make maps with no issues. Recently, I was given a slightly different shapefile of grid cells and asked to merge the two and re-generate the same maps. Now that I have joined the two sf objects, I can't get the map to plot.

I'm not sure how to create a reprex for this. The shapefiles themselves are freely available as `caltrawl.zip` and `CRFS/MAN_CA_CRFS_microblocks2013.zip` here: ftp://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/R7_MR/MANAGEMENT/

Here's the original code, that plots fine (this is just meant to summarize the "microblocks" to the resolution of interest to create a coarser/smaller object):

```
microblocks <- read_sf("CRFS_microblocks/MAN_CA_CRFS_microblocks2013.shp") 

blocks1 <- microblocks %>% 
  st_buffer(0) %>% # magical function that prevents errors when combining polygons below 
  group_by(BLOCK10_ID) %>% # so it doesn't just lump into one giant polygon ... 
  mutate(
    Xmean = mean(X),
    Ymean = mean(Y)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(BLOCK10_ID, Xmean, Ymean) %>% 
  summarise() %>% # should yield a sf object 
  ungroup() %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")
```

And `ggplot(blocks1) + geom_sf()` works fine.

However, when I try to join the second geometry `caltrawl`...

```
caltrawl <- read_sf("caltrawl/caltrawl.shp") %>% 
  dplyr::select(BLOCK10_ID) %>% 
blocks2 <- microblocks %>% 
  st_buffer(0) %>% # magical function that prevents errors when combining polygons below 
  group_by(BLOCK10_ID) %>% # so it doesn't just lump into one giant polygon ... 
  mutate(
    Xmean = mean(X),
    Ymean = mean(Y)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(BLOCK10_ID, Xmean, Ymean) %>% 
  summarise() %>% # should yield a sf object 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Xmean, -Ymean) %>% # since we're adding more blocks 
  as.data.frame() %>% # necessary to de-sf-ify to join the other blocks
  full_join(caltrawl, by="BLOCK10_ID") %>% # full join retains blocks from both
  st_sf(sf_column_name = 'geometry.x') %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")   as.data.frame()
```

I get an object that plots fine as `plot(blocks2)`, but when I try `ggplot(blocks2) + geom_sf()`, I get the following error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type standardGeneric. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Column `geometry` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list
```

It's also worth noting that they are both sf objects but the classes are somehow different:

```
> class(blocks1)
[1] "sf"         "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(blocks2)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

What am I doing wrong in the `blocks2` case?

Comment: I'm not clear what output you want. Can you give an example of the final map you want and why you need to merge the two layers?

Comment: I'm creating heatmaps of different environmental conditions for a client and they wanted me to use the most complete spatial data possible, which means merging these two slightly different data sources before making plots that fill the "blocks" by a color scale.

Comment: I haven't properly looked at the files yet but it seems like one is just a more detailed version of the other so what do you achieve by merging with the less detailed one? In terms of your error it could be that you are ending up with two geometry columns from the join so you might want to remove the unwanted one before making the join

Comment: This may not have been clear from the shorter reprex above, but: there are 916 spatial fishing blocks in this region. I have not been able to get a shapefile for all 916. Rather, I have two *different* incomplete files from the links above. They are quite similar (523 blocks in common) but each has ~12 extra blocks delineated that the other doesn't for some reason, which is why I am trying to merge them. Since they are both equally detailed, I think I have to keep both geometries?